# EXP utility through Java only exports few tables

Tags: java, oracle

I am using JAVA to do the Export the 250 table dump. I am preparing this exp command dynamically as table list is not fixed.

Below is snapshot of how I am building the syntax:

```
expCommand = "exp " + orclUserName + "/" + orclPassword + "@"
            + orclServiceName + " file=" + exportFilePath + dumpFileName
            + ".dmp log=" + exportFilePath + dumpFileName + ".log"
            + " TABLES=" + tableListCommandPlaceHolder + " statistics=none";

logger.info(" exp command == >   " + expCommand);
try {
        Process expProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(expCommand);
```

However when I run this java code, only 50 tables are getting exported. However if I manually executed the logged exp command from windows command line all the tables are getting exported correctly.

Any idea on this?

Comment: can you post your `expCommand` resulting string?

Comment: What do the export logs show for the Java and manually-run versions?

Answer (score 0):

I was using prrocess.waitFor() command to wait the process ..this was causing exp process to wait ..After commenting this export is working fine now...